# D3.js smooth transition between color blocks

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to make a visualization with D3.js. In my visualization, I have a stack of color blocks. I noticed that there are thin grey edges between my color blocks, which I don't want to have. I am not sure where the problem comes from. Any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
var svg = d3.select(container).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var background = svg.append("rect")
    //.style("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(numcols))
    .rangeBands([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(numrows))
    .rangeBands([0, height]);

var colorMap = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([minValue,maxValue])
    .range([startColor, endColor]);

var row = svg.selectAll(".row")
    .data(dataValues)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "row")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + y(i) + ")"; });

var cell = row.selectAll(".cell")
     .data(function(d) { return d; })
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "cell")
     .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x(i) + ", 0)"; });

cell.append('rect')
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

row.selectAll(".cell")
    .data(function(d, i) { return dataValues[i]; })
    .style("fill", colorMap);

if(highlightCellOnHover){
    cell
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this).style("fill", highlightCellColor);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.select(this).style("fill", colorMap);
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is a bit hard to tell without your data.  can you post that or point to a working fiddle?  Consider this:  If your data results in each cell being translated by amount <z> in the y axis based on the height of the previous cell and that means the second cell starts at <z> rather than <z+1> that would cause an overlap of two cells which would result in the  darker line if there is some transparency involved.  Without a working model, it is hard to tell.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue with the code provided. Adding your css code might help to resolve the issue.

Comment: @JoseJimenez I think the problem I had was exactly what you mentioned here and I was able to solve it by adjusting the height of each cell. Thank you very much:)

Comment: @Gilsha Thank you for your help. I will remember to add a working fiddle next time.